# How to raise donations in magento 2.3.3 and control amount from admin

Tags: magento2, admin, amount

Here I want to implement a functionality to raise donations for particular time period.
[image]

I want this functionality on a CMS page whenever the user clicks on a particular amount it should get for checkout and should be donated.
If the user entered a custom amount that amount should also go for checkout.
Admin should have provision to change these 3 amounts and also have provision to enable disable amount and custom value.
Anyone have any idea how to achieve this 
Small help will be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to take a look at [this free extension for donation](https://marketplace.magento.com/experius-module-donationproduct.html#product.info.details.support). They have step by step installation guide in [here](https://marketplace.magento.com/media/catalog/product/experius-module-donationproduct-1-2-2-ce/user_guides.pdf). If you really new with Magento 2 and installing extensions, you may see [the guide on installing Magento 2 Extensions](https://docs.magento.com/marketplace/user_guide/buyers/install-extension.html).

However, if the free extension doesn't cover your needs or requirements. You may take a look at other priced extension, [here's one for an example](https://marketplace.magento.com/mageworx-module-donationsmeta.html).

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way, you can create and manage donation products (with custom options).

OR

You can add a custom form and manage custom attribute in quote and order

Comment: Can You guide me with the beginning i am new to magento .
plz guide me from scratch